# Angularjs refresh current route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

in currently using angular-ui-router in my angularjs app. With main routes triggered from ui-sref directive in the top nav. How can I refresh a route even if I'm clicking on the current route.

Also if I'm in a subroute, then I want to refresh the view with the main route view.

Do I move this navigation into a custom function called upon ng-click?

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was to create function within my controller:

```
 $scope.navigateTo = function(stateName){
        if($state.current.name == stateName){
             $state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
        }else{
            $state.go(stateName, {inherit:false});
        }
    }
```

this was then called from within my html via my ng-click directive:

```
ng-click="navigateTo('appname.resources')"
```